# Can I use any coarse drywall screws when fixing nail pops in the ceiling?

Tags: repair, ceiling, drywall-anchor

I have several nail pops in the ceiling sheet rock of my house and I've decided to finally address/fix them.  The house was built 40 years ago so I don't believe there is any underlying issue other than time.

I have a bucket of coarse thread screws left to me from a different project hanging green board in a bathroom and I'd like to use these rather than buy yet more.  However, I'm uncertain of the length (1-5/8") for ceiling drywall (which may only be 1/4"?) and the specific details of the screw (see pictures) such as the serrated head, etc.

---

[image: Package details of screws]

---

[image: Package details of screws]

---

[image: Screw close up]

---

Comment: Note those are not drywall screws they are for backer board and will tear the paper as I said in my answer. If you used them on “green board as in cement board you did the correct thing in the past, if you used them on green Sheetrock or water resistant Sheetrock you used the wrong product. The strength in Sheetrock is in the paper break that and you have no strength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use backer board screws they are designed to cut a bevel, 
The cut will tear the paper and that is your strength in Sheetrock.

You do not want to break the paper, this is even more important on ceilings! 
 use Sheetrock screws or bugle head Sheetrock screws these come in both fine and corse.

Answer (score 1):

They will work but it would be an unnecessary expensive option and can create other problems.

They would create a larger countersink hole because you have drive them in a little farther to get them below the surface of the drywall paper. The serrations will cause unnecessary tearing of the paper which will be a problem when covering the heads with mud and weaken the holding power that that the screws are there for.

It would be better to just get the correct screws for the job, 1" 1/4 or 1" 5/8  will work and you can use a drywall screw driver tip that sets them at the correct depth.

Comment: Because of the tearing of the paper they would not be the proper screw.

Comment: @EdBeal thanks, i made it more clear.